# SAS - reordering dataset variables based on month

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset whose column layout is like this:

```
Col1      Col2      Col3 
A_jan2018 A_feb2018 A_mar2018 
B_jan2018 B_feb2018 B_mar2018 
C_jan2018 C_feb2018 C_mar2018
```

I need to re-order the columns that start with A or B or C in such a format --

```
Col1      Col2      Col3 
A_Jan2018 B_Jan2018 C_Jan2018 
A_Feb2018 B_Feb2018 C_Feb2018 
A_Mar2018 B_Mar2018 C_Mar2018
```

The A,B,C prefixes need not be in any sorting order (meaning they can start with anything), but my requirement is to re-order them based on the month-year (meaning B_Jan2018 A_Feb2018 C_2018 is okay).

Is there any way of achieving this in SAS?

Comment: Well, if you're having small amount of variables, you can use `retain Col1 Col2 Col3 A_Jan2018 B_Jan2018 C_Jan2018 A_Feb2018 B_Feb2018 
           C_Feb2018 A_Mar2018 B_Mar2018 C_Mar2018;` before set. If not, then you have to create some additional helping variables to do this.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a free code writing service. You will get a better response if you make an attempt to solve your problem yourself and post a reproducible code example if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: Is that your actual data? Or are you trying to convey that data is currently in columns ordered by date and rows ordered by variable (A,B,C) and you want to transpose it to have columns by variable (A,B,C) and the rows ordered by date?  Do you have an id variable to indicate which variable a current row represents?  How do you know what date a particular column represents?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the data structure so that you have a long dat set instead of
   a short data set. (DATA STEP)
2. Separate out the prefix from date portion (DATA STEP)
3. Sort into your desired order (PROC SORT)
4. Transpose to desired format (PROC TRANSPOSE)

   ```
   %*create sample data;
   data have;
       informat col1 col2 col3 $10.;
       input Col1  $    Col2  $    Col3 $;
       cards;
   A_jan2018 A_feb2018 A_mar2018 
   B_jan2018 B_feb2018 B_mar2018 
   C_jan2018 C_feb2018 C_mar2018
   ;
   run;

   %*Make it wide table;
   data _long;
       set have;
       array _col(3) col1-col3;

       do i=1 to 3;
           prefix=scan(_col(i), 1, "_");
           date=input(scan(_col(i), 2, "_"), anydtdte.);
           value=catx('_', prefix, put(date, monyy7.));
           output;
       end;
       format date date9.;
   run;

   %*Sort by desired output;
   proc sort data=_long;
       by date prefix;
   run;

   %* transpose to the desired format;
   proc transpose data=_long out=want1;
       by i;
       var value;
   run;
   ```

If your data is exactly as posted and the output is transposed exactly then this also works but its entirely reliant on the source data being as specified and sorted correctly.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want2;
     var col1-col3;
run;
```

Comment: Just curious - is there any particular reason you use the `%*` comment format rather than `*;` or `/* */`?

Comment: Nope, It means I’ve been writing macros lately.